# How to populate a json array object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

here is my code:

```
var pictures = {};

for (var key in pics) {
    //just interested in the first 3 profile pictures.
    if (i < 3){
        var view = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            image: pics[key].source,    
            width: 'auto',    
            height: 'auto'
        });

        $.scrollableView.addView(view);

        //store in json object
        pictures['source'] = '[' + pics[key].source + ']';

        i++;
    } else {
        //break out of loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Ok I know in JSON to create a JSON Array the syntax is basically this:

```
[ { something, something 2, something 3 }],
```

how can I create an json array dynamically based on the code above.

```
pictures['source'] = '[' + pics[key].source + ']';
```

This only stores the last `pics[key].source` in the list.

Comment: Don't try to generate a JSON string manually. Create a Javascript object and use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: so basically create an array and then use json.stringify?

Comment: Well, yea. Right now you're overwriting your "source" property on your `pictures` object, hence only getting the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
var pics = [{ source: 'foo' }, { source: 'bar' }, 
            { source: 'foo' }, { source: 'bar' }];

var pictures = pics.slice(0, 3).map(function(pic, i){
    var ret = {};
    ret[i] = pic.source;
    return ret;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(pictures)); // [{"0":"foo"},{"1":"bar"},{"2":"foo"}]
```

Update based on comment:

```
var pics = [{ source: 'foo' }, { source: 'bar' }, 
            { source: 'foo' }, { source: 'bar' }];

var imgSources = pics.slice(0, 3).map(function(pic, i){
    return pic.source;
});

console.log({ images: imgSources }); // {"images":["foo","bar","foo"]}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/psMSY/

Comment: basically that { images: [img 1, img2, img3 ]}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var pictures = [];
// your code..........


pictures.push(pics[key].source);

//more code....


var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(pictures);
```

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: thanks that works, how can i create a multidimensional array, so that the json string has a key?

Comment: Are you talking about a dictionary? what do you need under pictures?
if you are talking about a complex object then:
var pictures = []; pictures.push({name:'pic1.jpg',date:'12-10-2013',takenBy:'david'});
now pictures[0] is a complex object.

Comment: so its like { images: [img 1, img2, img3 ]}